# What's the easiest way to remove the power rails of a breadboard?

Tags: breadboard

All of the breadboards I get come with an adhesive backing that, while keeping the metal rows inside the breadboard in, keep the power rails connected to the breadboard. I want to remove the power rails off of a few boards to make a common data bus, and this has proven difficult. It seems like there is an easier way then ripping off the whole adhesive pad or just cutting the adhesive. Is there and easier way?

Comment: care to share a picture?

Comment: Buy the version without the power rails....

Comment: I'd have to use a saw on my breadboard.

Comment: Easier than cutting the Foam Adhesive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut away, rip the adhesive off, get some kapton tape off of [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR9.TRC2.A0.H0.Xkapton%20tape.TRS0&_nkw=kapton%20tape&_sacat=0) to replace it. Kapton tape is great stuff, has a resistance that is second only to teflon (at least on my list, don't get all technical on me). If you don't like that, I have seen places in the past where you can buy a 2x~40 strip of breadboard that was a few years ago though.